# Flutter FirebaseMessaging setup

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

In `initState()` of the `_PushMessagingExampleState` class in the [example app](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart) for Flutter firebase_messaging 6.0.13, `_firebaseMessaging.configure` is called first, followed by `_firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions`.

However, in the firebase_messaging 6.0.13 API reference for the [FirebaseMessaging](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging-class.html) class, the first thing it states is:

> Your app should call requestNotificationPermissions first and then
>   register handlers for incoming messages with configure.

Which is correct?
I'm guessing the API reference is correct and the example app could be improved?

Answer (score 1):

Technically it doesn't matter but I have it set up as request permissions first, then configure. As an example of a working app:

```
  configureFcm() {
    if (!isConfigured) {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        _fcm.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((IosNotificationSettings data) {
        });

        _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
      }
      _fcm.configure(
        // in foreground
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          _handleNotification(message);
        },
        // onBackgroundMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        //   print('on background message $message');
        // },
        // in background
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          _handleNotification(message);
        },
        // terminated
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          _handleNotification(message);
        },
      );
      isConfigured = true;
    }
  }
```